# java mysql prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a simple insert into a database with java and its telling me my sql syntax is off. But when I copyed the string I printed out and put it into the sql command in phpmyadmin it executes the command properly and I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with my string query in java.

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement;

String physicanInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO physician_phi VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
statement = ddp.getConnect().prepareStatement(physicanInsertQuery);

statement.setString(1, "id");
statement.setString(2, "first");
statement.setString(3, "last");
statement.setString(4, "middle");
statement.setString(5, "male");
statement.setString(6, "8179999999");
statement.setString(7, "test@gmail.com");
statement.setString(8, "1991-5-15");
System.out.println(statement.toString());
statement.executeUpdate(physicanInsertQuery);
statement.close();
```

This is the query that is printed out before I execute it.

```
INSERT INTO physician_phi VALUES('FML123','FirstName','LastName','MiddleName','Male','8179999999','john@server.department.company.com','1991-2-7')
```

This is the error its displaying in the console

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at command.up.DoctorStore.exec(DoctorStore.java:65)

....
```

This is the table in the db.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the base `Statement.executeUpdate(String)` method, which has nothing to do with `PreparedStatement` and simply executes a string of raw SQL.

You need to call `statement.executeUpdate()` without parameters to use the derived method n `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I think I just died inside a little . . . man, why didn't I see that.
Thank you very much for the point out.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you need a terminating ; on your sql statement. Also you should look into JPA, which will do all this database querying itself